# Not able to post the file through curl on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have hosted my website on the amazon ec2 instance. But i am facing a problem there i.e. when we are trying to post files/images through curl it posts only the url to the target url but we need to post the image content over there. For posting the image we are using the below given code :

```
    $target_url = 'http://www.alvinmcbride.com/FaceReaderPOST/api/facereader/PostImage';
                        $post = array('myImage'=>'@'.$frame_existing_path);
                        $curl = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                        $result=curl_exec ($curl);
                        curl_close ($curl);

                        $api_emotions_array[$frame_time] = json_decode($result, true);
```

And in response it gives a message "Invalid image" for every image. So please suggest if i am doing something wrong. Because the same code working fine on other servers like shared/dedicated servers.

Comment: What web server? (E.g. nginx, tomcat). What does the code look like that accepts the POST?

Comment: We are using apache server to run php code on the web server. And 52.25.217.134 is the private IP at port 88. So for accessing the website please use the url : http://52.25.217.134:88/user.

Answer (score 0):

use curl_file_create() function it work for me on amazon hosting..

```
$tmpfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$filetype = $_FILES['image']['type'];   
$image_string =curl_file_create($tmpfile,$filetype,$filename);
```

Normally

```
$org_image_string = '@'.$tmpfile.';filename='.$filename;
```

work for me on local and other server but it not work on amazon hosted site. hence i use curl_file_create and it work well :)